# getSenderPos() function removal from the new versions of VEINS

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins

Maybe I am wrong, but I noticed that the function getSenderPos() was removed/moved from WaveShortMessage to BasicSafetyMessage in versions 4.5+

With version 4.4 - I was using getSenderPos() to calculate the distance between the 2 nodes, but was wondering what would be the best approach with version 4.6+?

Should I rewrite the code written for WSM exchanges in my VEINS app to do BSM exchanges instead or am I missing something?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: compared to earlier versions, Veins 4.6 mandates a much smaller [set of fields](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage.msg) to be passed from applications to the MAC layer. The base type implementing this set of fields is (somewhat confusingly) called `WaveShortMessage`. Feel free to extend the set of fields by inheriting from the base type as you see fit, then cast the received message to your type in the `onWSM` method.

For quick experimentation, the example application layer `BaseWaveApplLayer` that comes with Veins already implements messages to simulate WSAs and BSMs, but most likely you want to use an entirely new type of messages anyway, so I wouldn't recommend building on these types of messages for anything but the most simple investigations (and, even then, to check that you are setting parameters like message length appropriately).